# trying to use strtol() in c but its only working for the first argument

Tags: c, strtol

I'm just trying to put 4 command line arguments into 4 int. It works for the first argument but returns 0 for the rest I can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* pEnd;
    long li1, li2, li3, li4;
    li1 = strtol(argv[1],&pEnd,10);
    li2 = strtol(pEnd,&pEnd,10);
    li3 = strtol(pEnd,&pEnd,10);
    li4 = strtol(pEnd,NULL,10);
```

For example, if I run the program as `./a.out -5 5 3 9`, then the parsed values are `-5 0 0 0`.

Comment: What are the arguments?

Comment: i'v tried -5 5 3 9 and it returns -5,0,0,0

Comment: but i need them separate as li1=-5 li2=5 li3=3 li4=9

Comment: try ./a.out "-5 5 3 9"

Answer (score 2):

You give arguments `-5 5 3 9`. This means that

- `argv[1]` contains `"-5"`
- `argv[2]` contains `"5"`
- `argv[3]` contains `"3"`
- `argv[4]` contains `"9"`

You use

```
li1 = strtol(argv[1],&pEnd,10);
```

and now, `li1` contains `-5` and `pEnd` holds `""`, an empty string. The below statements fails and return 0 as `strtol` couldn't extract numbers from the empty string `pEnd`

```
li2 = strtol(pEnd,&pEnd,10);
li3 = strtol(pEnd,&pEnd,10);
li4 = strtol(pEnd,NULL,10);
```

To fix this problem, you can use

```
li1 = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
li2 = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10);
li3 = strtol(argv[3], NULL, 10);
li4 = strtol(argv[4], NULL, 10);
```

and remove `pEnd` as it is uneccessary.

An alternative way would be to do what [@BLUEPIXY suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347853/trying-to-use-strtol-in-c-but-its-only-working-for-the-first-argument#comment46881692_29347853),i.e, wrap the arguments in double quotes so that the whole thing(`-5 5 3 9`) becomes a single argument and `argv[1]` holds `"-5 5 3 9"`. When you do this, your code will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each number is being passed as a single argument, so in fact this would do what you want

```
long li1, li2, li3, li4;

li1 = strtol(argv[1], &pEnd, 10);
li2 = strtol(argv[2], &pEnd, 10);
li3 = strtol(argv[3], &pEnd, 10);
li4 = strtol(argv[4], &pEnd, 10);
```

Here you could check the `pEnd` to ensure validity of the input values, instead of forgetting that the program might be called with wrong input values and you wouldn't know why it doesn't work, a simple

```
if (*pEnd != '\0')
 {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: invalid input ... \n");
 }
```

would prevent a lot of problems in the long run.

Omitting error checking is one of the most common mistakes that c programmers apparent;y do, perhaps because it's a tedious thing to do in c, but that doesn't mean it's not **necessary**.

If you want your code to work, then you need to make the 4 numbers a single argument, that can be achieved by enclosing the numbers with double/single qoutes `""`/`''`.

Comment: I tried wrapping the numbers using single quotes, but it didn't work.  I saw that `argv[1]` was `'-5`, `argv[2]` was `5` etc. Are you sure wrapping it in single quotes will work?

Comment: I am absolutely sure, the single quotes in a shell script for instance, make their content literal, so much that even variables like `${variable}` are not expanded, the double quotes allow to expand variables, so in this particular case single or double is the same. And by the way ignoring the `endptr` in `strtol()` makes the whole function not necessary since you could use `atol()`, unless you need a non-decimal base. And not performing error checking is very bad practice.